# While checking the Internet connection, UIVIEW hidden is not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

When i am trying to find out, whether the internet is active or not. Before checking the internet, i tried to show a loading screen. But it works after the result of internet checking function.

My internet checking code is

```
class Activeinternet: UIViewController {


class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

    var Status:Bool = false
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://google.com/")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "HEAD"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
    request.timeoutInterval = 4.0
    var response: URLResponse?
    var urlData: NSData?
    do {
        urlData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest as URLRequest, returning:&response) as NSData
    } catch let error as NSError {
        // reponseError = error
        urlData = nil
    }



    if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
            Status = true
        }
    }

    return Status

}


}
```

calling the internet checking

```
self.internetloadsview.isHidden = false
self.internetloadsindicator.startAnimating()
if Activeinternet.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
    self.internetloadsview.isHidden = true
    self.internetdwnmsg.isHidden = true
}
else{
    self.internetdwnmsg.isHidden = false
}
```

Everything works fine. but

```
self.internetloadsview.isHidden = false
self.internetloadsindicator.startAnimating()
```

this code working after the result of the active internet checking

I want to show the uiview before the internet activity isConnectedToNetwork calling

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are calling it in `sync` way which block main thread. You have to call it in  `async` and handle call in completion handler.

```
func isConnectedToNetwork( completionHandler completion: @escaping (Bool)-> Void) {

    if let url = URL(string: "https://google.com/") {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
            data, response, error in

            if error == nil {
                completion(true)
            } else {
                completion(false)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

And call this functions with completion block like this

```
 isConnectedToNetwork { (isSuccess) in
        if isSuccess {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.label1.text = "Internet is Connected"
            }
        }
        else{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.label1.text = "Internet is not connected"

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your check is synchronous here

```
NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest
```

which blocks the main thread ,  you need to make it asynchronous and return a callBack

Comment: Don't forget to include a link to the original source if the code is copied from somewhere else (https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Comment: left it to the op